# MyPy Type Errors with Seek/Read Operations

Tags: python, mypy

I have some logic using `seek()`/`read()` that most definitely works but is receiving some typing errors when I run MyPy against the code. What I'm trying to figure out is what I can do to get MyPy to understand the types. Or, rather, what I can do to make the types more in line with what MyPy is expecting and still have working code.

I have looked up a series of resources on `seek()`, `read()` and so on but nothing that I've found gives me unambiguous advice on how to handle this situation.

The code in question is this:

```
def read_format(self) -> None:
    self.data.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

    data_format = self.data.read(4)

    if data_format.decode("latin-1") == "FORM":
        self.data.seek(8, os.SEEK_SET)

    if self.data.read(4).decode("latin-1") == "IFRS":
        self._file_format = FORMAT.BLORB
    else:
        self._file_format = FORMAT.UNKNOWN
```

For both of the `seek()` calls above, MyPy says this:

**Argument 1 to "seek" of "IOBase" has incompatible type "int"; expected "IOBase"**

For both of the `read()` calls above, MyPy says this:

**Argument 1 to "read" of "BufferedIOBase" has incompatible type "int"; expected "BufferedIOBase"**

The next bit to understand is how I have `self.data` defined. That is as such:

```
@property
def data(self) -> Type[BufferedReader]:
    """Binary data stream of the story file."""

    return self._file_data
```

And the `self._file_data` being referenced is in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, story_file: str):
    self._file_data = BufferedReader
```

Most of the examples I look up about Python regarding the `read()` function show it being used exactly as I have it. The same applies to the `seek()` function. But clearly this is not something that MyPy expects and I'm going on the assumption that MyPy is relevant based on how Python code should ideally be constructed.

Tangent: I have tried changing my type hint to this: `Type[BufferedIOBase]`. I did that since this seems to be what MyPy is expecting. I also tried changing the variable initialization as such: `self._file_data = BufferedIOBase`. This has no effect, the same errors appear. I also get a new one:  **"Type[BufferedIOBase]" has no attribute "name"**. That error is coming from another line in my code (`assert self.data.name == self.path`) and that works because BufferedReader has a `name` property, whereas BufferedIOBase does not.

Comment: Wait, as written in your example so far, you are making self._file_data be a class (the BufferedReader class) and not actually an instance of BufferedReader. Is that intentional?

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. I was actually trying to just indicate the type of what the variable was going to hold. But you are absolutely correct: what I did there was basically just say the variable is going to hold a class. Good call.